# img tag having white space at the bottom

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, html-table

I'm creating a wordpress page and creating a certain part with background image, The main issue was, one of the image in css is being cut or split here is the link to the site:

http://testpress.dramend.com/amend-2/ the image being split was loopmid.gif which was not connecting to looptop.gif here is the screenshot:

[image]

```
<tr>
   <td height="23"><img width="707" height="23" alt="" src="http://dramend.com/looptop.gif"></td>
</tr>
```

Have I done anything wrong in my CSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `display: block;` or you can use `vertical-align: bottom;` as well for the `img` tag since it is `inline` element by default...that will solve the issue.

Also, you  are using `table` for designing layouts which is just dirty.. Learn CSS Positioning, floats, and make layouts using other tags like `div`, `section` etc

Comment: Thanks Mr. Alien works like a charm! will keep note of that! Thanks again! It helps a lot

Comment: I have another css question on the same site I've asked, any chance to read my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015950/css-background-image-to-be-boxed-white-not-fullwidth Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using table for design, try using `div` and CSS Positioning

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `table` for designing layout, which is not suggested as Mr.Alien said, you may use `display:table;` for that `img` tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your css file please add following lines:

```
table, td, tr {
   margin:0; 
   padding:0;
}
```