# CSS small screen issue

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, resolution, screen-resolution

My query was about my wordpress site womensfertility n hormones. c o m 
if I view the site on a smaller screen with resolution like 1024 x 768
the site would look like this:

[image]

but if I view it on my normal computer screen with big resolution it looks good,
then if I scale it to iphone and ipad it would scale normal as it is responsive. I'm using optimizepress. I've just added a code to make the site boxed layout and to have a background image instead of full width. my code that I've added was:

```
.banner .logo img{width:200px}

.banner.centered-banner > .fixed-width .banner-logo {
       width: 100%;
}

.container {
   margin: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 0;
   position: relative;
  width: 75%;
}
```

I guess the  `width: 75%;` and the `.banner .logo img { width: 200px; }` makes the site looks that way, but I have no idea how to make the site look like boxed without doing that code. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

use [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /*code for screen with max with 600px*/
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  /*code for screen with max with 480px*/
}
```

**or:**

```
body { color: white; background: gray; font-size: .5in }

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    body { background: red; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 1023px){
    body { background: yellow; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
    body { background: green; }
}
```

for example :

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {

    .banner .logo img{width:140px}

    .banner.centered-banner > .fixed-width .banner-logo {
           width: 80%;
    }

    .container {
      width: 35%;
    }

}
```

Comment: it still show the same. Any help ? thanks I've tried adding  .banner .logo img{width:140px} .banner.centered-banner > .fixed-width .banner-logo {
           width: 80%;
    } 
the banner header would just be small but still sliced. It is smaller interms of width but the size is still the same and the image is just turned 1/2